# Is it possible to create UIImage from *.pdf file in framework resource of my pod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, cocoapods

I have a private pod with mentioned resources in my podspec, that includes storyboards and pdf resources (vector images)
All resources are copied as expected, I can access them using `NSBundle(forClass:)`
Is there a way to create UIImages from a project that uses this pod as framework? 
Inside my project XCode generates @1,x2,x3 png from pdf in build time, that are situated in assets catalogue and mentioned as "single vector". 
But how to achieve it for frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

```
-(void)splitPDF:(NSURL *)sourcePDFUrl withOutputName:(NSString *)outputBaseName intoDirectory:(NSString *)directory
{
CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)sourcePDFUrl);
size_t numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(SourcePDFDocument);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:directory];

NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
withIntermediateDirectories:NO
attributes:nil
error:&error])
{

NSLog(@”Create directory error: %@”, error);

return;

}

for(int currentPage = 1; currentPage <= numberOfPages; currentPage ++ )
{

CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, currentPage);

// CoreGraphics: MUST retain the Page-Refernce manually
CGPDFPageRetain(SourcePDFPage);

NSString *relativeOutputFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d.png", directory, outputBaseName, currentPage];

NSString *ImageFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:relativeOutputFilePath];

CGRect sourceRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(ImageFileName, sourceRect, nil);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(sourceRect.size.width,sourceRect.size.height));

CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0.0, sourceRect.size.height); 
//596,842 //640×960,
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawPDFPage (currentContext, SourcePDFPage);
 // draws the page in the graphics context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:relativeOutputFilePath];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: imagePath atomically:YES];

}
}
```

You can further find more [here](http://www.singsys.com/blog/convert-pdf-into-images-in-objective-c/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it!

Comment: don't forget to tick the correct answer for others.